# How to create a dataset array of images?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow

I'm was messing around with tensorflow, and I has made an image classifier on the mnist dataset. Now I'm trying to recreate that, but with my own dataset, but i'm having trouble just creating the array I want. For example-

```
(X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test)= mnist.load_data()
print(X_train.shape)
```

Output-

```
(60000, 28, 28)
```

Where 60000 is the number of images, and the 28, 28 is the image array.

Trying to create this 3d array with my 2 images, I wrote this program-

```
import numpy as np, random
import matplotlib.image as plt
X_train=[]
print("Preparing the dataset...")
for i in range(100):
    img= plt.imread(f"img/{random.randint(1,2)}.png")
    X_train= np.append(X_train, img)
print("Done...")
print(X_train.shape)
```

Here, I'm just trying to append my `img` array to another array `X_train`. But the output is-

```
Preparing the dataset...
Done...
(1510452,)
```

Why is it flattening the whole thing? I'm expecting the shape to be (100, x, y), where x and y is the image array. How do I fix this? Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you should do

```
import numpy as np, random
import matplotlib.image as plt
X_train=[]
print("Preparing the dataset...")
for i in range(100):
    img=plt.imread(f"img/{random.randint(1,2)}.png")
    X_train.append( img)
X_train = np.array(X_train)
print("Done...")
print(X_train.shape)
```

upon running this on my images , i got this output

```
Preparing the dataset...
Done...
(100, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: But it's showing ``` (100,) ```

Comment: yes because of this line ''' for i in range(100): '''

Comment: I know, but where are the other 2 dimentions?

Comment: please take a look at the recent update i made,  I got (100, 28, 28, 1) , if you dont get it then there is something with the images you're using

Comment: Oh yeah! It works, when the images are of the same size! Thanks!